# Call method on any array of structs that have underlying field

Tags: go, struct, slice

Let's say I have a bunch of structs (around 10).

```
type A struct {
    ID int64
    ... other A-specific fields
}

type B struct {
    ID int64
    ... other B-specific fields
}

type C struct {
    ID int64
    ... other C-specific fields
}
```

If I have an array of these structs at any given time (either `[]A`, `[]B`, or `[]C`), how can I write a single function that pulls the IDs from the array of structs without writing 3 (or in my case, 10) separate functions like this:

```
type AList []A
type BList []B
type CList []C

func (list *AList) GetIDs() []int64 { ... }
func (list *BList) GetIDs() []int64 { ... }
func (list *CList) GetIDs() []int64 { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### With general method on the slice itself

You can make it a little simpler if you define a general interface to access the ID of the `i`<sup>th</sup> element of a slice:

```
type HasIDs interface {
    GetID(i int) int64
}
```

And you provide implementation for these:

```
func (x AList) GetID(i int) int64 { return x[i].ID }
func (x BList) GetID(i int) int64 { return x[i].ID }
func (x CList) GetID(i int) int64 { return x[i].ID }
```

And then one `GetID()` function is enough:

```
func GetIDs(s HasIDs) (ids []int64) {
    ids = make([]int64, reflect.ValueOf(s).Len())
    for i := range ids {
        ids[i] = s.GetID(i)
    }
    return
}
```

Note: the length of the slice may be a parameter to `GetIDs()`, or it may be part of the `HasIDs` interface. Both are more complex than the tiny reflection call to get the length of the slice, so bear with me on this.

Using it:

```
as := AList{A{1}, A{2}}
fmt.Println(GetIDs(as))

bs := BList{B{3}, B{4}}
fmt.Println(GetIDs(bs))

cs := []C{C{5}, C{6}}
fmt.Println(GetIDs(CList(cs)))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IJxs40XZKt)):

```
[1 2]
[3 4]
[5 6]
```

Note that we were able to use slices of type `AList`, `BList` etc, we did not need to use `interface{}` or `[]SomeIface`. Also note that we could also use e.g. a `[]C`, and when passing it to `GetIDs()`, we used a simple type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).

This is as simple as it can get. If you want to eliminate even the `GetID()` methods of the slices, then you really need to dig deeper into reflection ([`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package), and it will be slower. The presented solution above performs roughly the same as the "hard-coded" version.

### With reflection completely

If you want it to be completely "generic", you may do it using reflection, and then you need absolutely no extra methods on anything.

Without checking for errors, here's the solution:

```
func GetIDs(s interface{}) (ids []int64) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    ids = make([]int64, v.Len())
    for i := range ids {
        ids[i] = v.Index(i).FieldByName("ID").Int()
    }
    return
}
```

Testing and output is (almost) the same. Note that since here parameter type of `GetIDs()` is `interface{}`, you don't need to convert to `CList` to pass a value of type `[]C`. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/k-N2NJFnMt).

### With embedding and reflection

Getting a field by specifying its name as a `string` is quite fragile (think of rename / refactoring for example). We can improve maintainability, safety, and somewhat the reflection's performance if we "outsource" the `ID` field and an accessor method to a separate `struct`, which we'll embed, and we capture the accessor by an interface:

```
type IDWrapper struct {
    ID int64
}

func (i IDWrapper) GetID() int64 { return i.ID }

type HasID interface {
    GetID() int64
}
```

And the types all embed `IDWrapper`:

```
type A struct {
    IDWrapper
}

type B struct {
    IDWrapper
}

type C struct {
    IDWrapper
}
```

By embedding, all the embedder types (`A`, `B`, `C`) will have the `GetID()` method promoted and thus they all automatically implement `HasID`. We can take advantage of this in the `GetIDs()` function:

```
func GetIDs(s interface{}) (ids []int64) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    ids = make([]int64, v.Len())
    for i := range ids {
        ids[i] = v.Index(i).Interface().(HasID).GetID()
    }
    return
}
```

Testing it:

```
as := AList{A{IDWrapper{1}}, A{IDWrapper{2}}}
fmt.Println(GetIDs(as))

bs := BList{B{IDWrapper{3}}, B{IDWrapper{4}}}
fmt.Println(GetIDs(bs))

cs := []C{C{IDWrapper{5}}, C{IDWrapper{6}}}
fmt.Println(GetIDs(cs))
```

Output is the same. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IQdVbKoJd2). Note that in this case the only method is `IDWrapper.GetID()`, no other methods needed to be defined.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no easy way.

You might be tempted to use [embedding](http://www.hydrogen18.com/blog/golang-embedding.html), but I'm not sure there's any way to make this particular task any easier. Embedding feels like subclassing but it doesn't give you the power of polymorphism.

Polymorphism in Go is limited to methods and interfaces, not fields, so you can't access a given field by name across multiple classes.

You could use [reflection](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) to find and access the field you are interested in by name (or tag), but there are performance penalties for that and it will make your code complex and hard to follow. Reflection is not really intended to be a substitute for Polymorphism or generics.

I think your best solution is to use the polymorphism that Go does give you, and create an interface:

```
type IDable interface {
    GetId() int64
}
```

and make a GetId method for each of your classes. [Full example](https://play.golang.org/p/AFii-MTKf2).

Answer (score 0):

Generic methods require the use of interfaces and reflection.